# Linker Errors when Building Assimp with Premake

Tags: c++, game-engine, assimp, premake

I'm implementing assimp 5.0.1 in an engine and I can't get to link it, I guess it's because of the way of including it, but I don't know what it is I'm doing wrong.

I'm in Windows, working with Visual Studio 2019 (C++) and the steps I took were building assimp with cmake as states in the documentation and copied the folders 'code/' 'contrib/' and 'include/' in the project, inside an 'Assimp' folder. With this, I made a premake file to build it within the project of the engine (I'm using premake5 as a generator).

The problem is that I'm getting 5 linker errors. I assume I'm not including some needed file in the premake. The linker errors are the next ones:
[image]

Including the files that contain the functions giving linker errors gives even more linker issues that I cannot solve by keep adding or including files, so I don't know exactly how to proceed.

In the premake file (copied below), if I, for instance, comment some definition like "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IFC_IMPORTER", it will trigger more linker errors (in this case for IFC functions), that's why I guess there's some wrong inclusion or something. Does anyone knows what it can be wrong? Would it be so helpful because I'm really lost, I've been with this like a week.

The premake file I'm using is the next:

```
project 'Assimp'
    kind 'StaticLib'
    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "On"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    defines
    {
        -- "SWIG",
        --"ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OWN_ZLIB",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_X_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_3DS_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD3_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MDL_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD2_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_PLY_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_ASE_IMPORTER",
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OBJ_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_AMF_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_HMP_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SMD_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MDC_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MD5_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_STL_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_LWO_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_DXF_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_NFF_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_RAW_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OFF_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_AC_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_BVH_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IRRMESH_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IRR_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_Q3D_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_B3D_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COLLADA_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_TERRAGEN_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_CSM_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_3D_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_LWS_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OGRE_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OPENGEX_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MS3D_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COB_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_BLEND_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_Q3BSP_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_NDO_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IFC_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_XGL_IMPORTER",
        --"ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FBX_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_ASSBIN_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_GLTF_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_C4D_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_3MF_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_X3D_IMPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MMD_IMPORTER",

        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_STEP_EXPORTER",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SIB_IMPORTER",     
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_MAKELEFTHANDED_PROCESS",
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FLIPUVS_PROCESS",
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FLIPWINDINGORDER_PROCESS",
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_CALCTANGENTS_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_JOINVERTICES_PROCESS",
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_TRIANGULATE_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_GENFACENORMALS_PROCESS",
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_GENVERTEXNORMALS_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_REMOVEVC_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SPLITLARGEMESHES_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_PRETRANSFORMVERTICES_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_LIMITBONEWEIGHTS_PROCESS",
        -- "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_VALIDATEDS_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_IMPROVECACHELOCALITY_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FIXINFACINGNORMALS_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_REMOVE_REDUNDANTMATERIALS_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FINDINVALIDDATA_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FINDDEGENERATES_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SORTBYPTYPE_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_GENUVCOORDS_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_TRANSFORMTEXCOORDS_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_FINDINSTANCES_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OPTIMIZEMESHES_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OPTIMIZEGRAPH_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SPLITBYBONECOUNT_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_DEBONE_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_EMBEDTEXTURES_PROCESS",
        "ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_GLOBALSCALE_PROCESS",
    }

    files
    {
        "include/**",
        "code/Common/Assimp.cpp",
        "code/Common/BaseImporter.cpp",
        "code/Collada/ColladaLoader.cpp",
        "code/Collada/ColladaParser.cpp",
        "code/Common/CreateAnimMesh.cpp",
        "code/Ply/PlyParser.cpp",
        "code/Ply/PlyLoader.cpp",
        "code/Common/BaseProcess.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/EmbedTexturesProcess.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/ConvertToLHProcess.cpp",
        "code/Common/DefaultIOStream.cpp",
        "code/Common/DefaultIOSystem.cpp",
        "code/Common/DefaultLogger.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/GenVertexNormalsProcess.cpp",
        "code/Common/Importer.cpp",
        "code/Common/ImporterRegistry.cpp",
        "code/Material/MaterialSystem.cpp",
        "code/Common/PostStepRegistry.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/ProcessHelper.cpp",
        "code/Common/scene.cpp",
        "code/Common/ScenePreprocessor.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/ScaleProcess.cpp",
        "code/Common/SGSpatialSort.cpp",
        "code/Common/SkeletonMeshBuilder.cpp",
        "code/Common/SpatialSort.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/TriangulateProcess.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/ValidateDataStructure.cpp",
        "code/Common/Version.cpp",
        "code/Common/VertexTriangleAdjacency.cpp",
        "code/Obj/ObjFileImporter.cpp",
        "code/Obj/ObjFileMtlImporter.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXAnimation.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXBinaryTokenizer.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXConverter.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXDeformer.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXDocument.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXDocumentUtil.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXImporter.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXMaterial.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXMeshGeometry.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXModel.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXNodeAttribute.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXParser.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXProperties.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXTokenizer.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXExporter.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXExportNode.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXExportProperty.cpp",
        "code/FBX/FBXUtil.cpp",
        "code/Obj/ObjFileParser.cpp",
        "code/glTF/glTFImporter.cpp",
        "code/glTF2/glTF2Importer.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/MakeVerboseFormat.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/CalcTangentsProcess.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/ScaleProcess.cpp",
        "code/PostProcessing/EmbedTexturesProcess.cpp",
        "contrib/irrXML/*",
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "include",
        "contrib/irrXML",
        "contrib/rapidjson/include",
        "code"
    }

    -- And more lines of platform-related configurations that have nothing to do
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be you can view some case you meet LNK 2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=msvc-160

Comment: That should be added in the assimp premake? I have a link to Assimp project in the engine premake, but should I do a link into the assimp.lib in the assimp premake?

Comment: Wait a minute, you built a CMake before? then you try create a premake version?

Comment: You mean that repo: https://github.com/AminAliari/assimp/blob/master/premake5.lua ?

Comment: Yes, so as I'm not really experienced in this kind of things, that may have been a mistake... What I did was to try to mimic what the repo you linked did, so I made a build with CMake and passed all I needed into the "Assimp" folder in the engine so I could build it from there with premake (each time the engine compiles), which it kinda doesn't makes sense but I don't know another way around

Comment: I think you need make your question more clearly. I also misunderstand the question, so my answer is wrong now, I will edit it again

Comment: CMake and Premake is same build system. CMake is hard to learn (complex syntax), but can be build code directly or generate IDE project. Premake is easier to use but feature is limited to generate project. You can choose one of them, no need to re-create new one.

Comment: Okay, so I don't need to build assimp with CMake I understand? However, that process would be thougher with premake, I assume... Anyway, I could use premake just as a project configurator, don't?

Comment: My idea was to build the assimp project with premake so that it could be a project inside my engine, but I don't know how to do that without involving CMake

Comment: I know what you want to do, one make file for project. Did you try compile @AminAliari assimp repo yet?

Comment: No, I was actually trying to compile the last release of assimp (5.x), the Amin's one is older I think, but I can try

Comment: If you didn't build his repo before, you should try. If it don't work, may be his repo isn't complete. If it work, may be he modified source code. Last commit is 2019, not old too much to try it

Comment: Yes, it works, tried also to use some assimp things and it works good

Comment: I wanted to use the 5.x because of the nice changelog they have (I guess I will just conform with this), but they also did a refactor on the project folders layout, so that's why I'm guessing that I have something wrong in the files included in the project

Comment: So, what I was mentioning in the question is that I manage to build the library in its 5.x version, doing a #include <assimp/postprocess.h>, for instance, works, but then using it (like, for example doing Assimp::Importer importer) triggers linker errors, shown in the image

Comment: Also, another update: I managed to build the 5.x dynamically (with a .dll), obviously without making a full project out of it, and I guess I will use that by now but it kinda piss me off that I can't manage to make it statically

Comment: Okay, now let's do next step port cmake to premake.  First, check out official version 2019 when he fork, use diff tool and compare his repo and official repo see what is different. Then check out and compare lastest official version 2021 and 2019 what is new. We can see what is difference between 3 repo and if you have a luck, you can make minor update that premake file, or not it will be major update for premake file. As you told the new features, I think the lastest changes so much when from 2019 to 2021, so you need update premake file.

Comment: "As you told the new features" - I think you will need make update because LNK 2019 docs mentioned a issue may be fall to this: "The object file or library that contains the definition of the symbol isn't linked", list cpp file is out of date.

Comment: I have 3 solutions of this issue: 1. Keep update premake file. Steps of this is try, if fail try again util this work

Comment: 2. use package manager (something like Conan, vcpkg, ...) you just add package you want to use, didn't re-create anything library, see author premake use vcpkg https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/1306#issuecomment-629693881

Comment: 3. Mix Premake project (your project) and CMake project (library) in one, see that: https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/658#issuecomment-268942202

Comment: I will try solution 2 and 3 before because it will keep seperate library and your project. Their library also up-to-date. Solution 1 is just use if you modify somethings.

Comment: Okay, I will try that as soon as I have some free time to compile it again statically, thanks for your answers :)